# Corresponding eigenvalues complex/real endomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, spectral-theory

Let $A:\mathbb{C}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{C}^n$ be a complex linear map that we write $A=A_1+iA_2$. Under the identification $\mathbb{C}^n\simeq\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ we can see $A$ as a real endomorphism
$$B=\begin{pmatrix}
A_1 & -A_2\\
A_2 & A_1
\end{pmatrix}.$$
How can I relate the (complex) spectrum of $A$ with the one of $B$?

Comment: For each eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$, both $\lambda,\bar \lambda$ are eigenvalues of $B$. If $\lambda$ is real, then $\lambda$ is also an eigenvalue of $B$ with twice the multiplicity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $V$ is a complex vector space, then $\mathbb{C}\otimes_\mathbb{R} V$ (considered as a complex vector space via the first coordinate) is naturally isomorphic to $V\oplus \overline{V}$, where $\overline{V}$ is $V$ with its scalar multiplication conjugated.  Explicitly, this isomorphism is the map $\varphi:\mathbb{C}\otimes_\mathbb{R} V\to V\oplus \overline{V}$ given by $\varphi(z,v)=(zv,\overline{z}v)$ (where $\overline{z}v$ is using the original scalar multiplication of $V$, not the conjugated one of $\overline{V}$); this is easily verified to be an isomorphism when $V$ is 1-dimensional and then the general case follows since every vector space is a direct sum of 1-dimensional vector spaces.

Applying this to $V=\mathbb{C}^n$, it follows that the complexification of $B$ is just the direct sum of $A$ and the conjugate $\overline{A}$.  It follows that the spectrum of $B$ is the union of the spectrum of $A$ and its conjugate.

---

Here's another way to think about it.  Let $J:\mathbb{R}^{2n}\to\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ be the multiplication by $i$ map, when we identify $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ with $\mathbb{C}^n$.  Note that $BJ=JB$ since $A$ is $\mathbb{C}$-linear.  Let $\lambda=a+bi\in\mathbb{C}$ and write $p(x)=(x-\lambda)(x-\overline{\lambda})$.  Since $B$ has real entries, $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $B$ iff $p(B)$ is not invertible.  Now observe that $$(B-(a+bJ))(B-(a-bJ))=p(B)$$ since $p$ has real coefficients (so all the $J$s on the left-hand side will end up cancelling and all that matters is that $J^2=-1$ and $J$ commutes with $B$).  Thus $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $B$ iff either $B-(a+bJ)$ or $B-(a-bJ)$ is not invertible.  But when we think of our vector space as $\mathbb{C}^n$ instead, $B-(a+bJ)$ is just $A-\lambda$ and $B-(a-bJ)$ is just $A-\overline{\lambda}$.  Thus $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $B$ iff either $\lambda$ or $\overline{\lambda}$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.